# mysql select statement with multiple where/conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following two tables in mysql:

users:

```
+--------+-----------+
| userId | userName  |
+--------+-----------+
| 1      | magnus    |
| 2      | fabiano   |
| 3      | alexander |
| 4      | veselin   |
+--------+-----------+
```

games:

```
+--------+---------+---------+
| gameId | userId1 | userId2 |
+--------+---------+---------+
| 1      | 1       | 2       |
| 2      | 1       | 3       |
| 3      | 2       | 3       |
| 4      | 2       | 4       |
+--------+---------+---------+
```

How can I construct a single query such that I get this below output of say, fabiano's opponents:

output:

```
+--------+-----------+
| gameId | userName  |
+--------+-----------+
| 1      | magnus    |
| 3      | alexander |
| 4      | veselin   |
+--------+-----------+
```

Edit1:

This was what I was trying and I wasn't able to get them into a single query:

- select fabiano's opponents [select * from games where 2 in (userId1, userId2);]
- read each of the rows, and check which of them is fabiano(2), and select the other userId
- from the userIds of these opponents, get their name from users table

Edit2:
Inspired by the answers below, I wrote this (they work):

```
-- NO JOIN
select x.gameId, users.userName from
(
select gameId, userId2 as id from games where userId1=2
UNION
select gameId, userId1 as id from games where userId2=2 
) as x, users 
where users.userId = id;

-- NO JOIN, NO UNION        
select x.gameId, users.userName from (
SELECT g.gameId,
    CASE WHEN userId1 = 2
            THEN userId2     
         WHEN userId2 =2
            THEN userId1
         END AS id
FROM games g) as x, users
where users.userId = id;
```

Comment: sounds like do my work for me

Comment: sorry if it sounds so ... any directions/hints please ?

Comment: Use a query to get opponents as userId1, write the same query to get opponents as userId2, and use a union to combine the two queries.

Comment: @ZeRuBuES I don't think so ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can union the two sets of data together, viz all games where Fabiano is User 1, with all games that he is in the role of User 2:

```
SELECT x.Opponent
FROM
(
    SELECT u.Name AS Opponent
    FROM games g
    INNER JOIN users u
    ON g.userId2 = u.UserId
    WHERE g.UserId1 = 2 -- Fabiano

    UNION

    SELECT u.Name
    FROM games g
    INNER JOIN users u
    ON g.userId1 = u.UserId
    WHERE g.UserId2 = 2 -- Fabiano
) AS x;
```

At this point as assume that Fabiano can't simultaneously both be `User1` and `User2`, as we would need to consider [UNION ALL vs UNION DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) :)

This could also be tidied up a bit into:

```
SELECT x.Opponent
FROM
(
    SELECT u.Name AS Opponent, g.UserId1 AS PlayerId
    FROM games g
    INNER JOIN users u
    ON g.userId2 = u.UserId

    UNION

    SELECT u.Name, g.UserId2 AS PlayerId
    FROM games g
    INNER JOIN users u
    ON g.userId1 = u.UserId
) AS x
WHERE x.PlayerId = 2; -- Fabiano
```

Comment: Thanks. Based on your answer, I wrote a simple, single query which is relatively easy for a beginner like me to read - I'm adding it to my question.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Apologies, I see I left off `gameId`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
SELECT `gamess`.gameId, `users`.userName
FROM users INNER JOIN
   (SELECT gameId, userId2 as userId
    FROM games
    WHERE userId1 = 2
    UNION
    SELECT gameId, userId1 as userId
    FROM games
    WHERE userId2 = 2) AS gamess
ON `gamess`.userId = `users`.userId
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this without a UNION clause will make it more performant

```
SELECT g.gameid,
CASE WHEN u1.userid = 2 -- fabino* 
            THEN u2.username
            else u1.username END AS Opponent
FROM games g
LEFT JOIN users u1
ON g.userId1 = u1.UserId
LEFT JOIN users u2
on g.userid2 = u2.userid
WHERE (g.UserId1 = 2 OR g.userid2 = 2) -- fabino
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT us.*
FROM users us
INNER JOIN games gs ON us.userId = gs.userId1
GROUP BY us.userId ,us.userName

Answer (score 0):

This query should be works all of common userid

```
   SELECT x.Opponent
  FROM
  ( 
    SELECT u.userName AS Opponent
    FROM games g
    INNER JOIN users u
    ON g.userId2 = u.UserId
    WHERE g.UserId1 in (select UserId from users where UserId in (select userid1 from games)) 
    UNION
    SELECT u.userName
    FROM games g
    INNER JOIN users u
    ON g.userId1 = u.UserId
    WHERE g.UserId2 in (select UserId from users where UserId in (select userid2 from games))  
  ) AS x;
```